micrometer @AutoConfigureObservability in all test alternative
I would like to know if there is an alternative for spring boot test to not have to add the annotation " in all test.
I have to add this annotation because in my Controller advice I have inject the tracer, to send in the error response back the trace ID to easy then identify the logs when an error is produced.
The main problem with this is that for all integration test I have to add the annotation "@AutoConfigureObservability", because if not I get an error from the controller advice class that need to inject the "micrometer.Tracer" interface and cannot be found.
Is a bit annoying having this annotation in all test classes so I would like to know if there is an alternative maybe be configuration or something different to not have to do this in all integration tests classes.
Thanks in advance

what spring boot version are you using?

Almost latest one 3.2.9.

I would probably open an issue for Spring Boot.

There is a property that enables it for all tests.
spring.test.observability.auto-configure=true

I found this property in the source code of ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory, which is part of spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-3.1.1.jar
